# Using NvD3 charts, how to get x axis and Y axis label for multichart?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I am using multiChart of nvd3 for dual Y axes purpose.
All series are Line series in my chart.

I want to show X-axis label and Y axis label.

The documentation http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#multiChart for this chart does not have a label property.

Can anyone guide me for showing the x and y1, y2 axes labels?

Comment: Try this `chart.showLabels(true)`

Comment: It doesnt work. i tried already. The documentation doenst support this property for multiChart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you'll need to set the axis labels as follows:

```
    chart.xAxis
        .axisLabel('X AXIS');        

    chart.yAxis1
        .axisLabel('Y AXIS 1');

    chart.yAxis2
        .axisLabel('Y AXIS 2');
```

Complete example at https://jsfiddle.net/ovvn/f0Lautw0/1/